# How to configure grails 3 for mongodb replicaset

Tags: mongodb, grails, database-replication

I am deploying a grails 3 app to a live server. A mongodb instance has been setup in replication mode and tested successfully from the live box. I tested with:

```
mongo -u uname -authenticationDatabase dbname ip-1.ec2.internal:27017/dbname -p password
```

I have used the `replicaSet` and `connectionString` as specified [here](http://gorm.grails.org/5.0.x/mongodb/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html#advancedConfig) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/). But in both cases it behaves as though no hosts config have been supplied thus defaulting to **localhost**. And since that's not set up it fails. Here is the **application.groovy**:

```
mongodb {
            replicaSet = [ "ip-1.ec2.internal", "ip-12.ec2.internal", "ip-3.ec2.internal"]
            host = "ip-1.ec2.internal" //This works for any of the hosts
            port = 27017
            username = "username"
            password = "password"
            databaseName = "dbname"
        }
```

I am using the latest versions:

```
grailsVersion=3.2.8 //It was the same for 3.2.5
gormVersion=6.0.9.RELEASE
gradleWrapperVersion=3.4.1 //It was the same for 3.0
```

Here are the list of plugins with their versions:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.1.0'
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:6.0.9.RELEASE'
```

And this is the error I ran into:

```
01:22:26.410 - [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - No server chosen by 
ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, 
all=[ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: 
Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='username', source='dbname', password=<hidden>, 
mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 
'Authentication failed.' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response 
is { "ok" : 0.0, "code" : 18, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." }}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

I have ran out of options now, can anyone please point help me out here? Thanks.

Comment: This is the documentation http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/index.html#advancedConfig. I don't see anything about being able to specify the replicaSet that way. I think you just need to set up the url string

Comment: @JamesKleeh thank you, that worked great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [connection strings](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/index.html#_mongodb_connection_strings) as suggested by James Kleeh solved the issue. This is how I used it with reference from this [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#replica-set-with-members-on-different-machines):

```
mongodb {
    url = "mongodb://ip-1.ec2.internal,ip-2.ec2.internal,ip-3.ec2.internal/?replicaSet=hostname-of-mongod-instance"
    port = 27017
    ...
}
```